# How combine two channels by tuple elements in different positions?

Tags: groovy, nextflow

I have to combine the output of two different channels like these:

```
first_output = Channel.from(['H100_BDNA', 'sed'], ['H100_nova', 'rip'], ['H100_hiseq', 'bam2'])
second_output= Channel.from(['pAdna', 'H100_hiseq', '11'], ['pAsc', 'H100_BDNA', '45'], ['iMes', 'H100_BDNA', '58'], ['pAsc1', 'H100_nova', '23'])
```

The wanted result should be:

```
['pAdna', 'H100_hiseq', '11', 'bam2'], 
['pAsc', 'H100_BDNA', '45', 'sed'], 
['iMes', 'H100_BDNA', '58', 'sed'], 
['pAsc1', 'H100_nova', '23', 'rip']
```

That means joining the Channels by a common key represented by the first element of the tuple in the first output and the second element in the second channel.
I tried a lot of operators but no-one works.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to **decorate-combine-undecorate:**

```
second_output
    .map { tuple( it[1], *it ) }
    .combine( first_output, by: 0 )
    .map { it[1..-1] }
    .view()
```

Results:

```
[pAdna, H100_hiseq, 11, bam2]
[pAsc, H100_BDNA, 45, sed]
[iMes, H100_BDNA, 58, sed]
[pAsc1, H100_nova, 23, rip]
```

This works by prefixing the elements in the second channel with the key to be used to then [combine](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#combine) the items in the first channel. Note that we use the 'second version' of the combine operator to combine only those items that share a common key. Finally, we 'remove' the shared key by selecting all elements except the first element. See also: [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, in nextflow you can't specify the join-key position if it's different for two channels (`by` applies to both channels). The way I usually deal with it, is that I first rearrange the tuples in both channels in a way, that they can be joined using `map` and `swap`.

For your example (join `first_output`, key = 0 with `second_output` key = 1 and then reorder to have the desired output order) the approach would look like this:

```
second_output
    .map{it.swap(1,0)} // swap item 0 and 1
    .join(first_output) // now join on item 0
    .map{it.swap(1,0)} // swap back
    .set { joined_output }
```

edit:
I just realized, that you have 3 tuples in first and 4 tuples in second output. The behaviour of nextflow regarding `join`is indeed unintuitive as stated in [this discussion](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/discussions/1975)

They also provide a workaround function "inner_join":

```
def inner_join(ch_a, ch_b) {
    return ch_b.cross(ch_a).map { [it[0][0], *it[1][1..-1], *it[0][1..-1]] }
}
```

Using this function your solution would be (still swapping positions):

```
inner_join(second_output.map{ it.swap(1,0) }, first_output)
    .map{ it.swap(1,0) }
    .set { joined_output }
```

Comment: The "workaround" is not a viable option in my opinion. I'm not sure why it wasn't mentioned in the discussion, but the expected output could be obtained using: `left.combine(right, by: 0).view()`

Comment: @Steve yes, they are mentioning, that this "workaround" is not fully functional and here it might only work for this specific case where the keys of the smaller set are entirely present in the larger set.